# Figures with cite command used in caption do not appear in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

In my thesis, I am citing some of the figures using `\caption` command. However, these figures do not appear in list of figures.
I am using following command for caption

```
\caption[]{ PSD of two Sequences \cite{MCS2006}
```

Comment: Well, your optional argument of caption is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you used an empty square bracket in your command.  Thus, the content being transferred to your List Of Figures will be -- empty and non existent.

Use

```
caption{ PSD of two Sequences \cite{MCS2006}}
```

or

```
caption[PSD of two Sequences]{ PSD of two Sequences \cite{MCS2006}}
```

instead.